function Routes.hello_path/3 is undefined (module Routes is not available) in phoenix mvc
└─$ elixir -v
Erlang/OTP 27 [erts-15.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:12:12] [ds:12:12:10] [async-threads:1] [jit:ns]

Elixir 1.17.0 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 25)

Project Structure is following -
lib/
  hello/
  hello-web/
    components/
    controllers/
      hello_html/
        index.html.heex
        show.html.heex
      page_html/
      hello_controller.ex
      hello_html.ex
      page_controller.ex
      page_html.ex
    endpoint.ex
    gettext.ex
    router.ex
    telemetry.ex

mix.exs is following -
defmodule Hello.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :hello,
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.17",
      elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env()),
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      aliases: aliases(),
      deps: deps()
    ]
  end

router.ex is following -
defmodule HelloWeb.Router do
  use HelloWeb, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_live_flash
    plug :put_root_layout, html: {HelloWeb.Layouts, :root}
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", HelloWeb do
    pipe_through :browser

    get "/", PageController, :home
    get "/hello", HelloController, :index
    get "/hello/:messenger", HelloController, :show

    # resources "/users", UserController
  end

  # Enable LiveDashboard and Swoosh mailbox preview in development
  if Application.compile_env(:hello, :dev_routes) do
    import Phoenix.LiveDashboard.Router

    scope "/dev" do
      pipe_through :browser

      live_dashboard "/dashboard", metrics: HelloWeb.Telemetry
      forward "/mailbox", Plug.Swoosh.MailboxPreview
    end
  end
end

hello_controller.ex is following -
defmodule HelloWeb.HelloController do
  use HelloWeb, :controller

  def index(conn, _params) do
    conn
    |> put_flash(:info, "Welcome back!")
    |> render("index.html")
  end

  def show(conn, %{"messenger" => messenger}) do
    render(conn, "show.html.heex", messenger: messenger)
  end
end

hello_html.ex is following -
defmodule HelloWeb.HelloHTML do
  use HelloWeb, :html

  embed_templates "hello_html/*"
end

index.html.heex is following -
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h2>Hello World from Phoenix!2</h2>

  <p>
    <a href={Routes.hello_path(@conn, :show, messenger: 'Frank')} class="text-orange-700">
      Say hello to Frank
    </a>
  </p>
</div>

show.html.heex is following -
<div class="jumbotron">
  <p>
    <a href="/hello" class="text-orange-700">
      Go back
    </a>
  </p>
  <h2>Hello <%= @messenger %></h2>
</div>

Now, issue is occurring in index.html.heex -

UndefinedFunctionError at GET /hello
function Routes.hello_path/3 is undefined (module Routes is not available)

Its complaining about `Routes.hello_path is undefined`.
I'm very new to phoenix, and got stuck here for 5 hours, tried to understand manually, checked the controllers, router definition in `router.ex`, even tried Gemini LLM, no luck!
It's look like Phoenix framework is not that much easier and also not that much stable and very tough to learn compared to `ReactJS`, `NextJS` or `Django`.
adding hello_web.ex module -
defmodule HelloWeb do
  @moduledoc """
  The entrypoint for defining your web interface, such
  as controllers, components, channels, and so on.

  This can be used in your application as:

      use HelloWeb, :controller
      use HelloWeb, :html

  The definitions below will be executed for every controller,
  component, etc, so keep them short and clean, focused
  on imports, uses and aliases.

  Do NOT define functions inside the quoted expressions
  below. Instead, define additional modules and import
  those modules here.
  """

  def static_paths, do: ~w(assets fonts images favicon.ico robots.txt)

  def router do
    quote do
      use Phoenix.Router, helpers: false

      # Import common connection and controller functions to use in pipelines
      import Plug.Conn
      import Phoenix.Controller
      import Phoenix.LiveView.Router
    end
  end

  def channel do
    quote do
      use Phoenix.Channel
    end
  end

  def controller do
    quote do
      use Phoenix.Controller,
        formats: [:html, :json],
        layouts: [html: HelloWeb.Layouts]

      import Plug.Conn
      import HelloWeb.Gettext

      unquote(verified_routes())
    end
  end

  def live_view do
    quote do
      use Phoenix.LiveView,
        layout: {HelloWeb.Layouts, :app}

      unquote(html_helpers())
    end
  end

  def live_component do
    quote do
      use Phoenix.LiveComponent

      unquote(html_helpers())
    end
  end

  def html do
    quote do
      use Phoenix.Component

      # Import convenience functions from controllers
      import Phoenix.Controller,
        only: [get_csrf_token: 0, view_module: 1, view_template: 1]

      # Include general helpers for rendering HTML
      unquote(html_helpers())
    end
  end

  defp html_helpers do
    quote do
      # HTML escaping functionality
      import Phoenix.HTML
      # Core UI components and translation
      import HelloWeb.CoreComponents
      import HelloWeb.Gettext

      # Shortcut for generating JS commands
      alias Phoenix.LiveView.JS

      # Routes generation with the ~p sigil
      unquote(verified_routes())
    end
  end

  def verified_routes do
    quote do
      use Phoenix.VerifiedRoutes,
        endpoint: HelloWeb.Endpoint,
        router: HelloWeb.Router,
        statics: HelloWeb.static_paths()
    end
  end

  @doc """
  When used, dispatch to the appropriate controller/live_view/etc.
  """
  defmacro __using__(which) when is_atom(which) do
    apply(__MODULE__, which, [])
  end
end


Could you also share your HelloWeb module? It should be defining  something like alias HelloWeb.Router.Helpers, as: Routes in its __using__ macro, but it seems Routes has not been undefined here. Phoenix is overall quite stable, but there has indeed been some changes regarding route helpers: they have been replaced by verified routes in a recent release. So you might want to replace Routes.hello_path(@conn, :show, messenger: 'Frank') by ~p"/hello/Frank" instead.

Hi @sabiwara , hello_web.ex module added, also I created my phoenix project mix phx.new hello command.

thanks for the update. This is what I thought, this project has been created by a phoenix 1.7+ generator but the code is using an old pattern. In this case, replacing Routes.hello_path(@conn, :show, messenger: 'Frank') by ~p"/hello/#{"Frank"}" is probably what you want.

<a href={~p"/greetings/#{'Frank'}"} class="text-orange-700"> but it's throwing the following -
protocol Phoenix.Param not implemented for ~c"Frank" of type List. This protocol is implemented for the following type(s): Any, Atom, BitString, Float, Integer, Map

Single quotes are used for charlists, you want to use a string so you have to use double quotes.


Phoenix has changed the way to generate URLs in the 1.7 release, which introduced verified routes to replace the old route helpers.
Before (<1.7)
mix phx.new would generate a MyAppWeb file, which would contain a line like
alias HelloWeb.Router.Helpers, as: Routes

which you would use as follows is in your view:
Routes.hello_path(@conn, :show, messenger: 'Frank')

After (1.7+)
mix phx.new would now generate a MyAppWeb where this has been replaced by the def verified_routes snippet that you shared.
use Phoenix.VerifiedRoutes,
  endpoint: HelloWeb.Endpoint,
  router: HelloWeb.Router,
  statics: HelloWeb.static_paths()

You can now declare routes using the ~p sigil:
~p"/hello/#{"Frank"}"
# or
~p"/hello/#{[messenger: "Frank"]}"

The sigil is just adding some compile time validation, but at runtime it is eventually just going to generate the "/hello/Frank" string.
This change doesn't impact existing projects created using a generator predating the change. The MyAppWeb file has to be changed manually as explained in this guide.

Instead of giving name ~p  as Sigil (nearly no-meaning in English), it would be fun part if they would have given name Shazam (nearly no-meaning in English), but atleast people would have remembered it long enough simply...
